# Sql Compact, determine ROWGUIDCOL

Tags: sql-server-ce, information-schema

How does one determine ROWGUIDCOL property in a SQL Compact database?

Compact schema is exposed through INFORMATION_SCHEMA only, and as half expected, I'm having no luck finding Microsoft's proprietary ROWGUIDCOL property information inside.

Comment: Does `SELECT ROWGUIDCOL FROM YourTable` work in SQL Compact?

Comment: Error Code: 80040E14
 Message   : There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = ROWGUIDCOL ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only (undocumented) way that I know of:

```
SELECT column_flags, ... FROM information_schema.columns
```

If the value of column_flags is 378 or 282, the column is ROWGUIDCOL

(You can also use my Scripting API to get this info, saves you writing SQL code)

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ, looks like this works pretty well. Link to the scripting API?